# error in sending request from AsyncFacebookRunner

Tags: android, facebook

Here is my code to post data on user facebook wall but but getting error in request 
here is my code here is my code here is my code here is my code here is my code here is my code

```
private void postToFacebook(String review) {
    mProgress.setMessage("Posting ...");
    mProgress.show();

    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putString("message", review);
    params.putString("name", "Dexter");
    params.putString("caption", "londatiga.net");
    params.putString("link", "http://www.londatiga.net");
    params.putString(
            "description",
            "Dexter, seven years old dachshund who loves to catch cats, eat carrot and krupuk");
    params.putString("picture", "http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/6hqd44");

    mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST",new WallPostListener());

}
```

Here is error image
[image]

EDIT:
Here is my Login activity

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.sunil.R;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    // Facebook APP ID
    public static String APP_ID = "3***********";
    // Instance of Facebook Class
    public Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    public AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    Person person = new Person();

    // Buttons
    Button btnFbLogin;
    String fb_userid;
    String fb_useremail;
    String fb_username;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);
        // Add code to print out the key hash
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.example.authenticationdemo",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:",
                        Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
        // check if you are connected or not
        if (isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are NOT connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        // Implementing Login button functionality
        btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        /**
         * Login button Click event
         * */
        btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
                loginToFacebook();
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to login into facebook
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void loginToFacebook() {

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        // Check access token is present or not
        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            getProfileInformation();
            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            person.setFacebook_access_token1(facebook
                                    .getAccessToken().toString());
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();

                            getProfileInformation();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors
                        }

                    });
        }

    }

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            person = new Person();
            return POST(urls[0], person);
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(result);

            try {
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(result);

                // And then read attributes like
                String message = parentObject.getString("Message");
                String status = parentObject.getString("Status");
                String hash_key = parentObject.getString("hash_key");
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Status: " + status + "  Message: " + message
                                + " Hash_Key" + hash_key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Transaction.class);
                //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.putExtra("key", hash_key);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static String POST(String url, Person person) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            jsonObject.accumulate("email_id", person.getFacebook_emailid1()
                    .toString());
            jsonObject.accumulate("device_type", "Android");
            jsonObject.accumulate("facebook_user_id", person
                    .getFacebook_user_id1().toString());
            jsonObject.accumulate("screen_name", person
                    .getFacebook_user_name1().toString());
            jsonObject.accumulate("facebook_user_name", person
                    .getFacebook_user_name1().toString());
            jsonObject.accumulate("facebook_access_token", person
                    .getFacebook_access_token1().toString());
            /*
             * JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
             * 
             * jsonObject.accumulate("hash_key", "Daily");
             * jsonObject.accumulate("fb_post_frequency",
             * "9afc15d212107f03d08037290631df5****");
             */
            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the
            // content
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                System.out.println(result);
            } else
                result = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    /**
     * Get Profile information by making request to Facebook Graph API
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void getProfileInformation() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                    // getting name of the user
                    person.setFacebook_user_name1(profile.getString("name"));

                    // getting id of the user
                    person.setFacebook_user_id1(profile.getString("id"));

                    // getting email of the user
                    person.setFacebook_emailid1(profile.getString("email"));

                    // final String user_id = profile.getString("")
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            fb_useremail = person.getFacebook_emailid1()
                                    .toString();
                            fb_userid = person.getFacebook_user_id1()
                                    .toString();
                            fb_username = person.getFacebook_user_name1()
                                    .toString();
                            //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Name: " + fb_username + "\nEmail: "+ fb_useremail + "   id:"+ fb_userid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            new HttpAsyncTask()
                                    .execute("http://www.powe****************");
                                            + "/account/signup_map");
                            // new
                            // HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://www.powercheck.icloco.com/rest/index.php"+"/account/fbpostfrequecy");
                        }
                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: which facebook sdk you using for this

Answer (score 0):

use this code for `facebook 2.x` sdk this sdk deprecated that's why error showing. try to use `facebook 3.x` sdk

`NOTE:` as for your requirement this is working once try this

```
 private void SendRequest() {

    try {
        String response = facebook.request("me");
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", "contentStr");
        parameters.putString("description", "data");
        parameters.putString("name", "name");
        parameters.putString("picture","http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/6hqd44");
        parameters.putString("link", "http://www.londatiga.net");
        response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("")
                || response.equals("false")) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Blank Response...");
        } else {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting nullpointer exception at   String response = facebook.request("me");

Comment: EDited could you check my Login activity